# MS CRM 2016 Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector OrganizationServiceProxy is null

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

The problem is in connection to MS CRM 2016 by Xrm.Tooling.Connector. There is bug. When you get object from connection method OrganizationServiceProxy is null.

We solved this problem 2 days and on the end problem was in invalid app.config in section system.serviceModel. When we repair all errors, everything was ok. I hope this solution help to other people.

Comment: Is this a question? an answer? a statement? all of the above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be an answer posted as a question

Comment: It is solution for problem with connection to ms crm by sdk. There is bug. When you try connect to crm by Microsoft. Xrm.Tooling.Connector you get object and OrganziationServiceProxy is null. I thing it is bug in crm sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I find last CRM error in connection object. You can get the message by reflection.

```
public void TestInit()
    {
        var str = "Url=https://*****; Domain=***; Username=***; Password=****; authtype=AD;";
        mysvc = new CrmServiceClient(str);

        var crmConSvc = GetInstanceField(mysvc.GetType(), mysvc, "CrmConnectionService");
        var logEntry = GetInstanceField(crmConSvc.GetType(), crmConSvc, "logEntry");
        var lastErrorMethod = GetInstanceMethod(logEntry.GetType(), logEntry, "get_LastError");

        var message = lastErrorMethod.Invoke(logEntry, null);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    internal static object GetInstanceField(Type type, object instance, string fieldName)
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
            | BindingFlags.Static ;
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName, bindFlags);

        return field?.GetValue(instance);
    }

    internal static MethodInfo GetInstanceMethod(Type type, object instance, string methodName)
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
            | BindingFlags.Static;
        MethodInfo met = type.GetMethod(methodName, bindFlags);

        return met;
    }
```